# Need to find one element of table joinig 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two tables based on the result of a select (?)
I want to get the `distance` values of a user in table A with specific `unique_id` and `pos_id` and join them with table B `order_id`

I have this 2 Tables:

Table A has Fields `uniq_id` and `pos_id`.

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| unique_id       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time_stamp      | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start_id        | int(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| end_id          | int(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pos_id          | int(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

TableB has `order_id` and `distance`

```
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| order_id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| latitude      | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude     | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| distance      | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I get the `uniq_id` (e.g. 'user1') with that filter form A the `pos_id` and join it with `order_id` of B to get the corrseponding `disntace` values

I tired this but does not really get me there.

```
select distance from B
    join A
    on A.unique_id='user1'
```

I want to get the `distance` values from table B but all im I am getting now is **all** the distance values times 3 as aoutput.

Edit some sample data:
Table A

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------+--------+----------------+
| unique_id | time_stamp          | start_id | end_id | pos_id         |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+--------+----------------+
| user1     | 2019-04-24 14:40:15 |     NULL |   NULL |              1 |
| user1     | 2019-04-24 14:40:15 |     NULL |   NULL |              2 |
| user1     | 2019-04-24 14:40:15 |     NULL |   NULL |              3 |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+--------+----------------+
```

Table B

```
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| order_id  |     latitude        | longitude       | disntace      |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|     1     |    2.02347          | 11.438619613647 |     1.2764224 |
|     2     |    13.20476         |  -57.17261      |     29.082539 |
|     3     |   -31.60947         |  51.72054       |     13.158945 |
|     4     |   -56.01120         |  -154.53439     |      33.69381 |
|     5     |    29.68856         |  -130.61082     |     25.275803 |
|     6     |    48.03862         |  164.51725      |      14.42865 |
+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please include some sample data.

Comment: You say in your question that you join using `pos_id` and `order_id` but yet you don't do that in the query. What happens if change the ON clause to `ON a.pos_id = b.order_id AND A.unique_id='user1'`?

Comment: Thanks Joakim that did the trick !!

Answer (score 0):

for this you need a foreign key.....
i think **pos_id**  is the foreign key of tableB refarance column in **order_id**.
then your query look like  as

```
select B.distance from A
inner join B on (A.pos_id= B. order_id)
where A.unique_id='user1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
select distance from B
    join A
    ON a.pos_id = b.order_id AND A.unique_id='user1'
```

Answer (score -1):

i just start study sql for few months ago, but still don't see in examples "JOIN" tables by 1 field to contain 2 field. May be you need to write smthing like 
`SELECT distance From A,B Where a.unique_id = 'user1';`

Try this but don't judge me hardly :)

Comment: @pantha istiaque - why you JOIN fields, what not been equal ( 1 - pos_id (int 20), 2 - order_id (int 11) and what will if pos_id will be 12 symbols?

Comment: This is a very bad way to do it, use JOIN as this is the modern syntax rather that a comma separated list of tables and either way you do it you still need to define the relationship between the tables in your query.